# Websocketsharp getting QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext and System.ObjectDisposedException exception

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I'm trying to get the captcha token [from here](https://www.habbo.com.br/api/public/captcha?) using websocketsharp but I've got this error

```
29/08/2022 22:00:05|Error|QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute|Operation is not supported on this platform.
29/08/2022 22:00:06|Fatal|<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<ReadBytesAsync>b__0|System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
                          Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
                             at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.<ThrowIfDisposed>g__ThrowObjectDisposedException|63_0()
                             at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                             at WebSocketSharp.Ext.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<ReadBytesAsync>b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Javascript code is loaded in TamperMonkey

Javascript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Captcha Service
// @namespace    mservice
// @version      1.0
// @description  no description
// @author       Moch
// @match        https://www.habbo.com.br/api/public/captcha*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
    socket.onopen = () => {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        if (urlParams.has("token") && urlParams.get("token") !== "") {
            socket.send(urlParams.get("token"));
        }
    }
})();
```

C#:

```
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;
public class Laputa : WebSocketBehavior
{
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var wssv = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");

    wssv.AddWebSocketService<Laputa>("/");
    wssv.Start();
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    wssv.Stop();
}
```

I tried switching to WebSocketSharp-netstandard and WebScoketSharkFork but the same error appears.